# How to provide custom deleter in my class unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I've implemeted my unique_ptr:

```
template<class T, typename D = default_deleter<T> >
class unique_ptr
{
private:
    T* _ptr;
    D  deleter;
public:
    //Default constructor
    explicit unique_ptr(void): _ptr(nullptr) { }

    //Constructor with the provided pointer to manage
    unique_ptr(T* p) throw() : _ptr(p), deleter(default_deleter<T>()) 
{ }
    unique_ptr(T* p, D d) throw() : _ptr(p), deleter(d) { }
 ~unique_ptr(void) throw() // never throws
 {
     delete _ptr;
     _ptr = nullptr;
 }
```

Here it is a default_deleter

```
template<typename T>
struct default_deleter
{
    default_deleter() { }

    template<typename _Up>
    default_deleter(const default_deleter<_Up>&) { }

    void operator()(T* p) const
    {
        delete p;
    }
};
```

but when I am trying to use custom deleter:

```
struct MyCustomDeleter {
    void operator()(SomeResource* p) {
        p->releaseResources();
        delete p;
    }
};
int main() {
unique_ptr<SomeResource, MyCustomDeleter> ptr1(new SomeResource(1));
```

I get 
 no matching function for call to 'MyCustomDeleter::MyCustomDeleter(default_deleter)'

Comment: What is the reason behind implementing your own `unique_ptr` class? What problem does it solve that [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) doesn't solve?

Comment: For starters, post the *real* code in a [minimal, *complete*, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: it is the real code, that will be upgraded later.

Comment: You claim you get an error about `MyCustomDeleter` but there is no such symbol in the code you show. Please  create a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And when editing the question for the code, also copy-paste (as text) the full and complete (without any modifications) the output from the compiler.

Comment: *"it is the real code"* - It is ? Interesting, because the error message you're saying you get is about `MyCustomerDeleter`, yet the class posted is `CustomDeleter`. Also, the template parameter to `default_deleter` is `typename _Tp`, yet `operator()` references a phantom type `T`?. Regardless, it's wrong anyway, as the `deleter(default_deleter<T>())` in the `unique_ptr` constructor should be `deleter(D())`.

Comment: sorry, I updated my code, because of during creating this post, I changed name of some values, here is the normal code

Comment: You should not use the `throw()` specifier because it has been deprecated. I think it may even be removed in `C++17`

Answer (score 0):

You always initialize your unique_ptr with the default deleter, but there are inconsistencies in your code.

```
template<class T, typename D = default_deleter<T> >
class unique_ptr
{
private:
    T* _ptr;
    D  deleter;  // you do not need this, since the type is known at c-t
public:
    //Default constructor
    explicit unique_ptr(void): _ptr(nullptr) { }  // but no initialization of D

    //Constructor with the provided pointer to manage
    unique_ptr(T* p) throw() : _ptr(p), deleter(default_deleter<T>()) // wrong D !!
{ }
    unique_ptr(T* p, D d) throw() : _ptr(p), deleter(d) { }  // weird

};
```

You know the deleter at compile-time.

```
template<class T, typename D = default_deleter<T> >
class unique_ptr
{
private:
   T* ptr_{nullptr};
public:
   explicit unique_ptr(T* ptr) noexcept : ptr_(ptr) {}

   unique_ptr() noexcept = default;
   unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
   unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& x) noexcept : ptr_(x.release()) {}
   ~unique_ptr() noexcept(noexcept(D(T*{}))) { reset(); }

   void reset() noexcept(noexcept(D(T*{}))) 
       { if (ptr_) { D(ptr_); } ptr_ = nullptr; } 

   T* release() noexcept { auto p = ptr_; ptr_ = nullptr; return p; }

   unique_ptr& operator= (const unique_ptr&) = delete;
   unique_ptr& operator= (unique_ptr&& x) noexcept(noexcept(D(T*{}))) 
       { reset(); ptr_ = x.release(); return *this; };

   // ... operators op*, ->, etc... 
};
```

If you want to specify a deleter at run-time, it should not be a template parameter.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, I understood the problem and fixed it.